# Upgrade Magento 2.1.9 to Magento 2.2

Tags: magento, composer-php, magento2

---

i try to upgrade my Magento 2.1.9 to Magento 2.2 by composer but i get this following log :

```
  Problem 1
- magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.1 requires magento/module-wishlist 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist[100.1.6, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5].
- magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.0-rc1 requires magento/module-wishlist 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist[100.1.6, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5].
- magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.0-rc2 requires magento/module-wishlist 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist[100.1.6, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5].
- magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.0-rc3 requires magento/module-wishlist 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist[100.1.6, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5].
- magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.0 requires magento/module-wishlist 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist[100.1.6, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5].
- magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.1 requires magento/module-wishlist 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist[100.1.6, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.6].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.0-rc1].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.0-rc2].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.0-rc3].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.0].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.1].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.2].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.3].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.4].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.5].
- Can only install one of: magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0, 100.1.6].
- magento/product-community-edition 2.2.0 requires magento/module-wishlist 101.0.0 -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist[101.0.0].
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.0].
- Installation request for magento/module-wishlist-sample-data 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-wishlist-sample-data[100.1.1, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0].
```

I try 2 solution but none of them work

1.Take the composer.json from Magento official repo from branch magento2.2 but still i get errors.

2.Upgrade from the web setup wizard inside the admin but i get the same error about the composer on the installation check validation

Anyone got a solution for it?

Resources 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/component-depend.html

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/comp-mgr/cli/cli-rc1-samp.html - its for upgrade to Magento 2.1 but its on label Magneto 2.2

possible solution: 
Maybe i need to merge it with the composer official repo on branch M 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove all the sample data modules..like 20+ before it let me upgrade to 2.2

composer remove magento/module-wishlist-sample-data

and so on for all the modules.